# Dictionary<> value count c#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have dictionary object like this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<int>()>;
```

The number of keys is not very large but the list of integers in the value can be quite large (in the order of 1000's)

Given a list of keys (keylist), I need to count the number of times each integer appears for each key and return them ordered by frequency.

Output:

```
{int1, count1}
{int2, count2}
...
```

This is the solution I have come up with:

```
var query = _keylist.SelectMany(
             n=>_dictionary[n]).Group(g=>g).Select(
                 g=> new[] {g.key, g.count}).OrderByDescending(g=>g[1]);
```

Even when this query produces the desired result, it's not very efficient.
Is there a clever way to produce the same result with less processing?

Comment: "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it." --Brian Kernighan

Comment: How are the lists generated?  It would be potentially faster to calculate the frequencies as you build it.

Comment: This query is used to search the dictionary many times with any combination of strings (keys). I can't know upfront what these searches are going to be, and the dictionary is just too large to pre-calculate every possible search

Comment: @DoctorLai How is LINQ inherently related to "not efficient" code? I would argue the algorithm chosen (and clarity of such), not using/avoiding LINQ, is more important ..

Comment: @user2864740 That's what I was trying to figure out as well. The idea that inlining micro-algorithms like `Select` and `Where` will make the code faster (from an algorithmic point of view) is wrong.

Comment: (Anyway, I've downvoted this question because it contains *invalid* "working code".)

Comment: @user2864740 Programming is full of trade offs. You can't always have your cake and eat it too. Saying that a given algorithm is inefficient then asking for a clever solution to me is an oxy moron. The two are on different ends of the spectrum. You often need to make code ugly and straight forward if you want to make it more efficient. LINQ is clean and expressive, but people abuse it without giving thought to how it's doing what it's doing. LINQ does not automatically make something inefficient, but it does lead people to write such code.

Comment: @Despertar Sure you can (within functional requirement bounds). In fact the currently posted answer *uses* LINQ (or as much of LINQ as Enumerable.OrderBy uses) refutes any such claim that LINQ is unsuitable for this task. The first comment is *uncalled for* as a general heuristic; 5 up-votes (and unfortunately counting) on such wide claim irks me. In any case, I go by the 97/3 rule.

Comment: @user2864740 No one said LINQ could not be used to solve this. It's that the question is presented as "I tried this LINQ statement and it's not efficient". It shows no effort or initiative to actually solve the problem and this seems to be a recurring theme on SO. People ask "How do I solve this problem with LINQ?". This is an example of trying to get the problem to fit into your desired solution instead of the other way around.

Comment: @DoctorLai It's unfortunate that this falsehood is being perpetuated. When you say "do not use LINQ if you want efficient code" what you are really saying is "do not use functional programming concepts if you want efficient code." That is *wrong*. Armed with an understanding of what the out-of-the-box LINQ methods are actually doing internally, LINQ can be a powerful tool for expressing more-concise, more-efficient algorithms than is typically achieved when choosing to inline every micro-algorithm (which usually results in the author sacrificing algorithmic efficiency for legibility).

Comment: @TimothyShields  well, that is arguable. Linq allows you to write less for complex tasks, but you have less control of what is going on underneath, so you have to rely on the compiler, which may not produce most efficient code in all cases.. I agree that Linq's performance is not that bad but in some cases, trust me, LINQ is not the best choice.

Comment: @user2864740  see my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

From an algorithmic space- and time-usage point of view, the only thing I see that is suboptimal is the use of `GroupBy` when you don't actually need the groups (only the group counts). You can use the following extension method instead.

```
public static Dictionary<K, int> CountBy<T, K>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, K> keySelector)
{
    return source.SumBy(keySelector, item => 1);
}

public static Dictionary<K, int> SumBy<T, K>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, K> keySelector,
    Func<T, int> valueSelector)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    if (keySelector == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("keySelector");
    }
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<K, int>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        var key = keySelector(item);
        int count;
        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out count))
        {
            count = 0;
        }
        dictionary[key] = count + valueSelector(item);
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

Note the advantage is that the lists of numbers are enumerated but not stored. Only the counts are stored. Note also that the `keySelector` parameter is not even necessary in your case and I only included it to make the extension method slightly more general.

The usage is then as follows.

```
var query = _keylist
    .Select(k => _dictionary[k])
    .CountBy(n => n)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Value);
```

This will you get you a sequence of `KeyValuePair<int, int>` where the `Key` is the number from your original lists and the `Value` is the count.

---

To more efficiently handle a sequence of queries, you can preprocess your data.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>> preprocessedDictionary
    = _dictionary.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value.CountBy(n => n));
```

Now you can perform a query more efficiently.

```
var query = _keylist
    .SelectMany(k => preprocessedDictionary[k])
    .SumBy(p => p.Key, p => p.Value)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Value);
```

Comment: I believe GroupBy for L2O is still O(n). That is, while this does avoid intermediate objects, I wonder what both the wall-clock and/or complexity differences are in terms of ".. [is] not very efficient. Is there a clever way to produce the same result with less processing" ..

Comment: @user2864740 `GroupBy` is basically doing what this `CountBy` method does, except instead of storing an `int` in the dictionary value, it's storing a `List<T>` where `T` is the source type. They both run in O(n) time, but `GroupBy` uses O(n) space whereas `CountBy` uses O(k) space where k is the number of unique keys. When k is much less than n and n is huge, this can be a big performance improvement because of the `List<T>` allocation costs.

Comment: Hopefully the OP will try this method and provide some real-world benchmark results. I'm not entirely sold that it's a "deal breaker" .. but it might be, and this does avoid the extra memory usage and provides an explanation, so you have my vote.

Comment: @user2864740 I agree that, in the asker's situation, this will probably be irrelevant. He says "in the order of 1000's." But maybe not.

Comment: Doing some tests now, just a min... i'm getting an exception somewhere. The example i'm trying has 50k keys and an average of 90k ints in the value (a bit extreme but I have the benchmark numbers from my approach)

Comment: Ok I didn't let it run till the end but for some reason this is extremely slow. My approach was taking 45 minutes for the whole process and after 15 minutes I stopped this new version at 2% completion. VS profiler is marking the extension method in red as the bottle-neck (exactly the for-each inside)

Comment: @FranCasadome Either you're running your experiments on a von Neumann potato or there's something important that you're not telling in the question. :) I just tried this code on my machine with 10^8 values and 10^5 keys and it ran in just a few seconds. Yes, the `foreach` loop is "the bottleneck" - you **have to** loop through all your values to count them.

Comment: @TimothyShields hahaha! well yes, there are a lot more things going on that I didn't tell you about but they occur before (generating the initial dictionary) and after (using the results of the search).
What is taking 45 minutes is not one single search but a lot of them: approximately 50k^2 / 2 of them

Comment: @FranCasadome Oh you're doing that many. That's a lot. Are you parallelizing your searches? That's the first thing you should do. The second thing you could do is a one-time compacting of each `(string, List<int>)` pairs into a `(string, Dictionary<int, int>)` pair. That way you are only merging count dictionaries at query time rather than enumerating through those huge lists repeatedly.

Comment: @TimothyShields I'm not parallelizing my searches.. I wouldn't even know where to start (i'm not very good at understanding how parallel code works). I like your second idea though i'll see if I can come up with a faster solution with it

Comment: @FranCasadome I just edited my answer to include this "preprocessing" idea. Depending on how repeated or distinct the values are in each source `List<int>` this could be a big or little improvement, respectively.

Comment: @TimothyShields That's neat. I'll add another clue to the problem (I didn't think this was important): there are no duplicates in each list on ints for each key in the dictionary. Each List<int> only contains unique int values. Does this simplify things?

Comment: @FranCasadome It simplifies things in the sense that the preprocessing I suggested becomes worthless...

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

```
var query =
    from k in _keylist
    from v in dictionary[k]
    group v by v into gvs
    let result = new
    {
        key = gvs.Key,
        count = gvs.Count(),
    }
    orderby result.count descending
    select result;
```

To me this is quite straight forward and simple and well worth accepting any (minor) performance hit by using LINQ.

---

And alternative approach that doesn't create the large list of groups would be to do this:

```
var query =
    _keylist
        .SelectMany(k => dictionary[k])
        .Aggregate(
            new Dictionary<int, int>(),
            (d, v) =>
            {
                if (d.ContainsKey(v))
                {
                    d[v] += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    d[v] = 1;
                }
                return d;
            })
    .OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value)
    .Select(kvp => new
    {
        key = kvp.Key,
        count = kvp.Value,
    });
```

Comment: What is the difference with my proposal? Other than the verbose linq syntax?

Comment: @FranCasadome - To start with, it compiles. Otherwise it doesn't create arrays of integers, instead it creates anonymous type. And it uses query-syntax (hopefully making it easier to read).

Comment: @FranCasadome - I added an alternative that may be quicker. Can you test?

Comment: Ok, sorry if I offended you, that wasn't my intention at all. The result of the query is the return value for my search function (IEnumerable<int[]>), so I can't return an anonymous type

Comment: Wouldn't the line d[v] = 1 throw an exception since the dictionary doesn't contain the key yet?

Comment: @FranCasadome - No, it doesn't. If the key doesn't exist it adds it.

Comment: @FranCasadome - You should have mentioned the `IEnumerable<int[]>` requirement in your question, but you should be able to change my second query to easily return your array.

Comment: @Enigmativity How is this different than my answer (besides inlining the behavior)?

Comment: @Enigmativity It seems the Aggregate is also very inefficient, even more than the extension method for-each according to VS profiler